# My server does not look up with static ips

Tags: server, static-ip

lately the users with **static ips can not look websites on my server** and they giving **not connection error**! but some of servers that are connect by `cloudflare` giving error 403

my webserver is `litespeed`

in errorlog just this replied :

```
PHP Warning:  php_uname() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Registry.php on line 814
```

Firewall deny ips:

```
173.205.184.60 # Manually denied: 173.205.184.60 (US/United States/-) - Tue Oct 27 10:16:15 2015
69.10.42.67 # Manually denied: 69.10.42.67 (US/United States/host.litespeedtech.com) - Tue Oct 27 10:16:15 2015
```

i'm really confused what maybe reason!!

Comment: Sorry but with the information provided its hard for the community to help at all, please edit your question and include access log, error logs and ban logs when the people affected visit your server (not the entire logs).

Comment: A 403 error is forbidden and there must be some kind of log of the event. Please add access/error logs of when this event is triggered, this could be local or on cloudflare. Please add this vital information otherwise the question will be placed back on hold.

Comment: @SimonHayter where can I found that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we check `access log` and we found:

our web server (`litespeed`) was banned some ips and we delete those in ban list

thanks for helps